# Error: seqdata should be a state sequence object, an event sequence object, or a suffix tree. Use seqdef or seqecreate

Tags: r, sequence, hidden-markov-models, seqhmm

I have a sequence of data (similar to protein data) and I want to use the mixture of hidden Markov model (mhmm) to cluster them. I chose `seqHMM` package to do it. but when I want to train a mhmm model, it gives this error:

```
build_mhmm(observations = dat, n_states = c(4, 4, 6))
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : seqdata should be a state sequence object, an event sequence object, or a suffix tree. Use seqdef or seqecreate.

I tried to structure for `dat`. One is normal sequences and the other is matrix of sequences.
For instance:

```
dat<-data.frame(matrix(c("e","f","j","o","d","o","p","k","k","a","d","c"),ncol = 4,nrow = 3))
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  e  o  p  a
#2  f  d  k  d
#3  j  o  k  c
```

and

```
matrix(paste(dat$X1,dat$X2,dat$X3,dat$X4),nrow = nrow(dat))
#1 "eopa"
#2 "fdkd"
#3 "jokc"
```

How should I change the format of my data in order to make it readable using `build_mhmm`? The data already exists and I don't want to recreate them using any package. I want to manipulate them and make them as a proper input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I should use `seqdef(dat)` form package `TraMineR` instead of `dat` in `build_mhmm` function